# Python: Handle Missing Object keys in mapping and continue instructions

Tags: python, json, exception, key, keyerror

I'm fairly new to Python so bear with me please.
I have a function that takes two parameters, an api response and an output object, i need to assign some values from the api response to the output object:

```
def map_data(output, response):
    try:
        output['car']['name'] = response['name']
        output['car']['color'] = response['color']
        output['car']['date'] = response['date']
        #other mapping
        .
        . 
        .
        .
        #other mapping
     except KeyError as e:
        logging.error("Key Missing in api Response:  %s", str(e))
        pass

     return output
```

Now sometimes, the api response is missing some keys i'm using to generate my output object, so i used the KeyError exception to handle this case.

Now my question is, in a case where the 'color' key is missing from the api response, how can i catch the exception and continue to the line after it `output['car']['date'] = response['date']` and the rest of the instructions.

i tried the `pass` instruction but it didn't have any affect.

Ps: i know i can check the existence of the key using:

```
if response.get('color') is not None: 
 output['car']['color'] = response['color']
```

and then assign the values but seeing that i have about 30 values i need to map, is there any other way i can implement ? Thank you

Comment: Create a list of the keys and a for-loop to iterate over them. In each iteration you can then in a try-block assign the key and if something goes wrong you can "pass" and the loop continues with the next key.

Comment: @MichaelButscher i thought of it but sometimes the key names between the output and api response change(output are French api resp are English ) and some keys are also nested

Answer (score 0):

A few immediate ideas

(FYI - I'm not going to explain everything in detail - you can check out the python docs for more info, examples etc - that will help you learn more, rather than trying to explain everything here)

0. Google 'python handling dict missing keys' for a million methods/ideas/approaches - it's a common use case!
1. Convert your response dict to a `defaultdict`.  In that case you can have a default value returned (eg None, '', 'N/A' ...whatever you like) if there is no actual value returned.

In this case you could do away with the `try` and every line would be executed.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
resp=defaultdict(lambda: 'NA', response)
output['car']['date'] = response['date']  # will have value 'NA' if 'date' isnt in response
```

2. Use the `in` syntax, perhaps in combination with a ternary `else`

```py
output['car']['color'] = response['color'] if 'color' in response
output['car']['date'] = response['date'] if 'date' in response else 'NA'
```

Again you can do away with the try block and every line will execute.

3. Use the dictionary `get` function, which allows you to specify a default if there is no value for that key:

```py
output['car']['color'] = response.get('car', 'no car specified')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a utility function that gets the value from the response and if the value is not found, it returns an empty string. See example below:

```py
def get_value_from_response_or_null(response, key):
    try:
        value = response[key]
        return value
    except KeyError as e:
        logging.error("Key Missing in api Response:  %s", str(e))
        return ""


def map_data(output, response):
    output['car']['name'] = get_value_from_response_or_null(response, 'name')
    output['car']['color'] = get_value_from_response_or_null(response, 'color')
    output['car']['date'] = get_value_from_response_or_null(response, 'date')
    # other mapping

    # other mapping

    return output
```

Comment: This would work, but really is a pretty convoluted approach to handling a common use-case that already has built-in to the core language approaches for handling directly.

Comment: I know about those approaches. I used a utility function because of the logging part, if you use `dict.get('value', 'value if not fould')` then you won't be able to log that a key is missing in the response.

Comment: True - good point!